# Mirror Modifier is visible in object mode but disappears in edit mode

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror

I made a circle in Blender and added a mirror modifier to it after deleting one-half of the circle. The mirror showed while in object mode, but when I switched to edit mode to start sculpting my character; the mirror disappeared.

How can I make the Mirror Modifier work properly?

Comment: Can you provide your blend file?

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable "Display modifier in edit mode". This icon is of a box with four orange corners, and can be found on the modifier node with the other visibility settings.

[image]

> Box
>
> Displays the modified geometry in edit mode, as well as the original geometry which you can edit.

Without:

[image]

And with:

[image]

If you enable the Triangle option next to the box one you can then also edit the transformation caused by the modifier on edit mode

[image]

> Triangle
>
> When enabled, the final modified geometry will be shown in edit mode and can be edited directly.

For a detailed description on the use of these options read this [page of the Blender manual.](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html#interface)