# Subdivision surface modifier problem

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, edges, faces

Hello! 
 
I've recently started learning Blender and faced one problem. 
After applying subdivision surface modifier I have plenty of extra faces.
I've watched some teaching videos and I suppose additional faces shouldn't be added.
Is it OK ? How to avoid this problem if it isn't.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried bumping up the Merge limit in your mirror modifer?

Comment: It's visible because you enabled the _display modifier in viewport and Editmode_. Maybe [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/56446/19287) or [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html#interface) helps. I also recommend to model with quads because tris (on the nose) and subsurf dont blend well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have some double vertices over there.
shortcut **W > remove doubles** might solve your problem. Also try to keep faces as quads. Subdivision surface with triangles doesn't give optimal result.